# Battery saving - WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, battery-life, 7.0-nougat

My WhatsApp messages have been delayed and I believe it is because of the power saving being on. I want to keep it on because my battery drains, but WhatsApp does not seem to be in the unmonitored apps list. Is this normal or how do I resolve? I'm on a Galaxy S6

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the `Settings` app,
- Go to `Battery`,
- Tap the `...` button in the upper-right corner,
- Tap `Battery Optimization`,
- Tap the `Not Optimized` drop-down and select `All Apps`.

**Disabling battery optimization for a specific app**

- Locate the app you want to disable battery optimization for.
- Tap the app in question.
- From the popup, tap `Don't optimize`.
- Tap `DONE`.

**Enabling battery optimization for a specific app**

- Locate the app you want to enable battery optimization for.
- Tap the app in question.
- From the popup, tap `Optimize`.
- Tap `DONE`.

Source: [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-remove-android-apps-from-the-battery-optimization-list/)